# Is the token which client's app receives by a BroadcastReceiver from GCM can't be captured by other applications on same device?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I just wonder when GCM sends the token to my app can any other apps on the same device receive it? 
And should I save it on the mob memory or request a new one each time the app is initiated?

Answer (score 0):

[GCM register() is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid). use [Instance ID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/) instead of it.

**What is Instance ID?**

Instance ID provides a unique ID per instance of your Android and iOS apps.

**Key features**

In addition to providing unique IDs for authentication, Instance ID can generate security tokens for use with other services.

**Instance ID lifecycle**

The Instance ID service issues an InstanceID when your app comes online.

The InstanceID is backed by a public/private key pair with the private key stored on the local device and the public key registered with the Instance ID service.

Your app can request a fresh InstanceID whenever needed using the getID() method. Your app can store it on your server if you have one that supports your app.

Your app can request tokens from the Instance ID service as needed using the getToken() method, and like InstanceID, your app can also store tokens on your own server. All tokens issued to your app belong to the app's InstanceID.

Tokens are unique and secure, `but your app or the Instance ID service may need to refresh tokens in the event of a security issue or when a user uninstalls and reinstalls your app during device restoration. Your app must implement a listener to respond to token refresh requests from the Instance ID service.`

Answer (score 0):

Calling instanceId.getToken(...) returns a token to your app only. This should be sent to your application server to be used to send messages to the app with the particular token.

There is no need to save it, actually saving it is discouraged. If you need the token again for some reason you can always call instanceId.getToken(...) again to get the same token, once the same instance of the application exists (ie no a new installation) and the token has not been deemed compromised by Google, then you will get the same token.

What is recommended is to save a boolean indicating whether or not you have sent the token to your app server, once your app server has it you should not have to generate it again.